# VS installer make the application automacatically start when OS boots

Tags: installation, windows-installer

All .

I have an Window application and wanna release it using VS2010 package installer.

One of the features of the package requires that the application automatically start up whenever OS boots. and the supported OS varies from Windows XP(x86/64) to windows 7 . Could you help to enlighten me to make a solution general to the mentioned OS.

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to package a .bat script with your project and create a Custom Action to call that file.  Call the `sc` command in it to create your service:

```
sc create "My Service Name" binPath= "C:\Program Files\My Folder\bin.exe" type= "own" start= "auto" DisplayName="My Service Name"
```

See [this article on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990289.aspx)

Comment: Yes.Need to create an execute file running after the installation .